# Java Reactive program

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My requirement is as follows.

Get ApptReq object which will have apptId. Get Appt object from DB and update Appt object with the data from ApptReq and update the table.

```
Mono<User> monoUser = retrieveUser();

public Mono<ServerResponse> updateAppt(ServerRequest request) {
        return apptRepository.findById(request.bodyToMono(ApptReq.class).map(ApptReq::getApptId)).flatMap(appt -> {
            return updateAppt(appt, request.bodyToMono(ApptReq.class)).flatMap(apptRepository::save).flatMap(
                    res -> ServerResponse.created(URI.create(String.format(APPT_URI_FORMAT, res.getApptId()))).build());
        });
    }



private Mono<Appt> updateAppt(Appt appt, Mono<ApptReq> apptReq) {

    return apptReq.map(req -> {
        appt.setNotes(req.getNotes());
        

        return monoUser.map((usr) -> {
            appt.setUpdatedBy(usr.getUserId());
            return appt;
        });
    });

}
```

Here getting error in updateAppt method that

> can not convert from Mono<Object> to Mono<Appt>.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: After the response put the id and the baseobject in a touple and pass it along

Comment: Sample please, am still confused with reactive.

Comment: I dont have the time to write your code, if you demand a code sample, then someone else will have to answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it almost. I changed nothing in your `updateAppt(ServerRequest request)` method but made just a slight adjustment in your `updateAppt(Appt appt, Mono<ApptReq> apptReq)` method, as follows:

```
    private Mono<Appt> updateAppt(Appt appt, Mono<ApptReq> apptReq) {

        return apptReq.flatMap(req -> {
            appt.setNotes(req.getNotes());


            return retrieveUser().map((usr) -> {
                appt.setUpdatedBy(usr.getUserId());
                return appt;
            });
        });

    }
```

Watch out for the `apptReq.flatMap` instead of your `apptReq.map` and everything works fine. Give it a try!

Reminder: Be careful with nested `Mono`s in other `Mono`s or more generally said nested `Publisher`s.

Comment: This works. I will accept this. Just wondering the best approach without the nested Mono's?

Comment: Well without them? To be honest I do not believe there is such way as long as you want to stay fully reactive in all intermediate steps. Will think about it and come back to you if something comes to my mind. :-)

Comment: updateAppt method is getting invoked, but not the code inside apptReq.flatMap. Not sure why it is not getting invoked.